# Getting an error - "afterRender threw an error in 'c:lwcLocationOnMap' [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]"

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Single Marker</h1>
    </div>
    <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers}></lightning-map>
</template>
```

JS

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    wire,
    track
} from 'lwc';

import getLocation from '@salesforce/apex/LocationOnMapController.getLocation';

export default class LwcLocationOnMap extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track error
    @track account = {};
    @track mapMarkers;

    @wire(getLocation, {
        accId: '$recordId'
    })
    wiredAccount({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            console.log('data>>' + JSON.stringify(this.account));
            this.mapMarkers = [{
                location: {
                    Street: this.account.BillingStreet,
                    City: this.account.BillingCity,
                    State: this.account.BillingState,
                    Country: this.account.BillingCountry
                },
                Title: this.account.Name,
                description: this.account.Name + ' billing address',
                icon: 'standard:account'
            }, ];
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.account = undefined;
            console.log('ERROR : ' + this.error);
        }
    }
}
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class LocationOnMapController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Account getLocation( String accId){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry 
        FROM Account 
        WHERE Id = :accId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial render is failing, resulting in the error you see. Try:

```
<lightning-map if:true={mapMarkers} map-markers={mapMarkers}></lightning-map>
```